# How to instantly inform search engines(google) to index new url's

Tags: search, indexing, seo, google-search, bing

I am working on creating a Q&A site like stack overflow for particular topics. Just like on Stack overflow when a new question is asked a dynamic url is generated for example `mysite.com/questions/{id}/{title}` how can I get search engines to index these new url's immediately a new question is asked.
Like

```
if(question.asked()){
url = question.url;
search_engines.index(url);
}
```

Is there any API provided by popular search engines like Google and Bing to automatically inform them about new url's? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your new URL-s dynamically in xml sitemap. xml sitemap helps all search engines crawling your website.
2. Go to Search Console or Bing Webmaster tools and ask them indexing your new URL-s.

They have their own opinion indexing URL-s. You have to wait. That's all what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google search console, Then click on Fetch as google under Crawl.
There you can submit your latest url and click OK.
Goolgle will fetch your new url and can be seen in search results.

Answer (score 0):

add website to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

add website to https://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url

add site map

divide content add make indivisual site map

like https://bskud.com

its have one site map then its divide content by states

https://bskud.com/HIMACHAL-PRADESH-SITE-MAP.php

https://bskud.com/JHARKHAND-SITE-MAP.php